# .htaccess want 410 gone but getting 403 forbidden

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to deliver the 410 "Gone" header for all requests including root. I have added this .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteRule (.*) - [G,L]
```

Which works for requests to http://foo.bar/foo.html <-- Delivers 410! Great :-)

But if I request http://foo.bar/ <-- Delivers 403 Forbidden. Not great :-(

How do I rewrite the htaccess to just say EVERYTHING is gone?

Comment: did you set 'DirectoryIndex'? also, have you set 'RewriteBase /'?

Comment: No, those are the only 3 lines of logic in the file. Should I add "RewriteBase /" ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay then. Here's my "default .htaccess" file for any new portal. It works perfectly. Use it wisely :)
(my hotlink.jpg is a pink unicorn. You **had to** know this!):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteRule .* - [G,L,NC]
```

#DEFAULT PAGE/FILE
DirectoryIndex /site_all/index.php?uid=$1 [QSA,L]

#PROTECT .htaccess AND .htpasswd FILES
 < files .htaccess="" >
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
 < /files >
< files .htpasswd="" >
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
< /files >

### HACKING AND DIRECT-ACCESS PREVENTION ###

#PREVENT DIRECT PAGE ACCESS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.unclefoo.com/.*$ [NC]

#PREVENT HOTLINKS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg)$ http://www.unclefoo.com/site_data/pics/hotlink.jpg [R,L]

#PREVENT INVALID CHARS
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ [a-zA-Z0-9.+_/-\?\=\&]+\ HTTP/ [NC]
 #RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

#PREVENT ACCESS TO PHP.INI

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS

#PREVENT ACCESS TO INCLUDES DIR - TEST IF COMPROMISES WEB SERVER IF 3rd PARTY HOSTS!!!
 #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /site_data/includes/ .*$ [NC]
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+.php$
 #RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

#PREVENT DOWNLOAD/HACK TOOLS USAGE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]


Now you understand why one has to learn a bit about apache and .htaccess before get a site going? ;)
Hope this helps!

nth EDIT: Seems you are gone so here are my "last words" :)

 - Ask this question [here](http://serverfault.com) instead, you may or may not get better support than what I can give.
 - Potential issues you may have:
  ~ using virtual host (and not having `RewriteOptions Inherit` set).
  ~ foo.com/ maybe really is forbidden (e.g. your default page is whatever.html and no rights to access that file)
  ~ as above but having a 404 and a `ErrorDocument 404 /err403.html` setting somewhere
  ~ you have a symbolic link to your "gone html" but `Options FollowSymLinks` is disabled
  ~ same `RewriteRule` has been configured in multiple files (e.g. .htaccess and httpd.conf) and it causes the headaches
Either way, I'd recommend checking your site's dirs, path settings, links and sym links to be sure all files are there and accessible.
And as a *workaround*, I'd skip the `RewriteRule` and would do `ErrorDocument 4XX /410.php` instead ('4XX' stands for 401, 402, 403, 404, etc).

Still hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really help as I still don't understand what lines might help me make the root deliver 410 instead of 403.  You realise I am trying to completely close down the site. Make everything deliver 410 gone. This is frustrating because I did it a few weeks ago with a different site but deleted the file since.

Comment: @MartinJoiner are you having a virtual host? (ps modified thingie above, added the items you probably need - which I asked in question comment)

Comment: @MartinJoiner also added your lines in the way I think it should work. If you have virtual host, you also need to add 'RewriteOptions Inherit'